# jQuery Ajax POST to Rails 3.2.2 not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a simple .ajax post to a rails scaffold project running on Heroku:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', url: "http://herokuserver/images.json",
            data: { image: { name: "johngalt1" } }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

As it turns out using the javascript console in Chrome I get:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://herokuServer/images.json. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

HOWEVER, when I go to the rails app on heroku a new record has been created with the name => "johngalt1". From everything I've read I thought the cross-domain issue with javascript would have prevented the record being created and required me to use json-p or CORS? Or does the javascript cross-domain issue only prevent receiving data from a server via javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only prevents the browser from receiving data.  So if you don't need a response from this post, you should be ok.

edit - when I'm developing locally, I create a rewrite rule for the Apache2 server on my mac to get around this limitation. it creates a reverse proxy that tricks the browser into allowing cross-domain requests.

Comment: You can also use the rack cors middleware to do it (https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) if you don't want to use Apache in dev