# Are there substantial differences in the way browsers implement the same-origin policy?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, cors

I have a form on my homepage that is set up to submit via XHR POST to the URL https://mydomain.com/send_sms.

When I visit the non-SSL version of the homepage in Internet Explorer (http://mydomain.com) & submit the form, nothing happens. In Webkit console, I receive a helpful error stating `Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

In Firefox 13 however, the request clearly submits & a returns a `200 OK`, though the response body is blank. Furthermore, the server-side action (sending an SMS) is in fact triggered by the Firefox request but not the other browsers.

I always thought the same-origin policy denied even the sending of the request, but perhaps it's the browser receiving data from the response that's disallowed?

Anyone know if this is a purposeful difference in implementation (or possibly even an oversight) by Mozilla?

Comment: I can indeed make cross protocol requests (at least http->https) in firefox 13 but not in google chrome. I tested on a server that doesn't send CORS headers even.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212071/jquery-ajax-post-to-rails-3-2-2-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` are different origins. For [XHR Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-XMLHttpRequest1-20120117/) this would mean, cross-origin requests are not allowed.

But for the current [XHR (Level 2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), which supports cross-origin requests when [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is supported (by both server and client!), a cross-origin request can either be

- a [simple cross-orgin request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-cross-origin-request), if

  - the request method is `GET`, `HEAD`, or `POST`, and
  - none of the request header fields is one other than `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Content-Language`, or `Content-Type`, and
  - the preflight flag is not set

  or
- a [cross-origin request that requires a preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight), otherwise.

For simple cross-origin requests, the browser is allowed to send the request. But when the response is received, it needs to [check whether the server allows to share the resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-sharing-check). This is where the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header field and other `Access-Control-*` response header fields are checked. And only if this check is passed, the browser allows the script to read the response.

For other cross-origin requests, a preflight is required to negotiate with the server what information is allowed to be sent in the actual request. This preflight request is basically a `OPTIONS` request telling the server what the actual request will contain (request method and header fields). Then the server can decide whether it allows such request or not.

In your case, the observed behavior can have multiple reasons. I guess your *send_sms* script just doesn’t [support the server side part for CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-processing-model).

Comment: Good answer! My knowledge of CORS was limited so glad someone with a deeper understanding could shed some light

Answer (score 0):

The sending of data should be prohibited just as much as receiving e.g. what if there was some malicious JS on this page and it was submitting each keystroke to some random server? In this instance, the sending is more nefarious than the receiving (as an aside, this can actually be achieved by requesting resources like images or scripts, with a query string, as they aren't subject to the same origin policy).

I have encountered slight differences in the past but that's usually been with legacy IE.

To me, the firefox discrepancy is a bug (providing a vanilla install has this trait). A different protocol (HTTP vs HTTPS) is equivalent to a different origin, even sub-domains on the same protocol are considered to be of different origin, so FF13 should definitely not be making the AJAX request.

You don't happen to have CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) set up, and FF13 is the only browser you've tested to support it?

Comment: CORS must send a request to see if the response contains an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header right? So the request is made and the server can handle it however it wants, it just can't return response data to the browser unless it sends that header along with it.

Comment: This is a Rails app, & this form uses Rails' out-of-the-box `data-remote` functionality through jQuery. No CORS setup & no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the response (though there is a `Set-Cookie` header, which seems troubling). Version 13 is the only Firefox I've tested with.

Comment: Anything specific to rails/Ruby should have no effect on the same origin policy as it is enforced at browser-level. So your tech-stack should be inconsequential. The `set-cookie` header is likely a session cookie if you're not setting a cookie yourself.

Comment: The primary purpose of CORS is not to allow the browser to deny sending requests to cross-origin (this can be done without XHR) but to allow the server to deny sending responses to cross-origin that the resource is not allowed to be shared with.